# Having Issue with basic Express routing

Tags: node.js, express, routes

So I'm working with Express for the first time, and don't know why one is working and the other does not

If I go to this URL: `localhost:3000/profile/:john` to hit this route, it will print 'hello world':

```
app.get('/profile/:name', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello world');
)
```

However, if I go to this URL: `localhost:3000/profile` to hit this route, it gives me a 403 error:

```
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello world');
)
```

Comment: FYI, the colon belongs ONLY in the Express route declaration here `app.get('/profile/:name', ...)`, not in the actual URL.  The actual URL should be `http://localhost:3000/profile/john`.  The `:name` is to tell Express that you want to define a parameter there.  The colon is NOT part of the incoming URL.  Then, when you use the proper URL `http://localhost:3000/profile/john`, it will match your `'/profile/:name'` route definition and `req.params.name` will contain `"john"`.

Comment: When arranging your code which came first ?